# How to create a div that will automatically word wrap the contents so that the div will never grow horizontally larger than its container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <select name="Country">
        <option value="1">Argentina</option>
        <option value="2">Australia</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <div id="description"></div>

    <input ...
    <input ...
    <input ...
    contents ...
    contents ...
</div>
```

The `#description` div will be filled in on the fly according to the selection option. I want so that the `#description` div will automatically wordwrap, and not forcefully expand the container, if one line is not enough to hold the content of `#description`.

The catch is, I don't want to give a fixed width to `#container` because I want the `#container`'s width to be flexible according to all the elements inside the container, *except* this `#description` div. I also don't want to give fixed width to `#description` either, because I want the `#description` div can grow / shrink depends on the `#container`.

The `#container` itself indeed can grow or shrink, but it only happened when the page loads, as it fills up select's options with current values, and other stuffs. But once the page finish loaded, I don't want the width of the `#container` to change, hence this dilemma. I have tried to give `#description` width 100%, but it does not work too. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: did you tried giving description's width to 100% and height as auto?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I've just tried it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: In that case, share a fiddle

Comment: is there any declaration of `width` of `container`? if not then give it and then use `width` of `#description`

Comment: @AtikurRahman that is the whole point. I don't want to specify the width because I want it to be flexible to all the controls within the container, *except* the description. The description needs to be able to word wrap according to the whatever current dynamic width of the container.

Comment: @gurvinder372 This is the fiddle. jsfiddle.net/chenliyong/283nwep7/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use word-wrap CSS property in your description block. In this case you can give width in percentage allowing the description div to widen or shrink according to the width of the container. You can also try out the `vw` for keeping the width of container and description in control and use word-wrap in parallel. Check out [**this link**](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for more information's on CSS `vw`.

```
#description{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Update with workaround:**

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/283nwep7/9/)

```js
preset = [];
info = [];
 
preset.push ("Select ");
info.push ("");
 
preset.push ("1. Top ");
info.push ("Print Ten Members who got the top results. For awarding purposes.");
 
preset.push ("2. New ");
info.push ("Print all new members of the month.");
 
preset.push ("3. Inactive ");
info.push ("Print all inactive members of the month. Including members who delete their profile.");

$( document ).ready(function() {
 for (var i = 0; i < preset.length; i++) {
  $('#options').append($('<option>', { 
   value: i,
   text : preset[i] 
  })); 
 }
});
  
$('#options').change(function(){
 var idx = $('option:selected',$(this)).index();
 $('#description').text(info[idx]);
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  border: black solid 1px;
  position:absolute;
  padding:20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 40%;
}

#options {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 80px;
}

input[type=button] {
  width: 50px;
}

#description {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <select id="options"></select>
  <input type="button" value="Print"/>
  <div id="description"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried the width + word-wrap method, and it doesn't work either. This `vw` attribute, on the other hand, even though it looks weird, is interesting. I'll try that in a moment.

Comment: @ChenLiYong did you specify width of your description and content in percentage or vs as suggested? word-wrap won't work without specifying width.

Comment: @ChenLiYong and can you provide a fiddle with the code you tried so that I can make sure if you are missing something?

Comment: I've created jsfiddle but there's no share code feature. Only share result. How can I share my jsfiddle? I have given title and description.

Comment: Oh, scratch that. I just need to copy the url. Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/chenliyong/283nwep7/2/

Comment: I understand what you're trying to achieve. The problem with that approach arise when the contents' width changed like this. https://jsfiddle.net/chenliyong/283nwep7/7/ That's why, I avoid to fix the width of the container.

Comment: I see your approach to limit the width of the dropdown. While this not entirely address the issue, but this workaround is great! This will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/283nwep7/6/)

here is the css required

```
html,body
{
  width:100%;
}

#container {
  width:60%;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  border: black solid 1px;
  position:absolute;
  padding:20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
#description
{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the revision. I understand with your approach. However, the reason I avoid fixing the length of the container is because if the contents' width shrinking, the container does not shrink as well. Please see this fiddle, a modification of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/chenliyong/283nwep7/8/

Comment: @ChenLiYong you will have to give width to the container in percentages. Otherwise, how will its decendents know what is the maximum width they can occupy? By giving in percentages the width of the container will still respond to the resize of the window.

Comment: yeah, at the end, I finally accepts that it's impossible to do it with css alone. So I do it with the jquery help to save the `#container`'s width after document ready while the `#description` is hidden, and then show it and apply the width to it manually. Too bad, I was hoping that I can make the CSS portable without the need of any JS accompanying. Thanks anyway. :)